# Phpstorm, форматирование css

Tags: css, phpstorm

Допустим имеется такой css-код:

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    .button{
        color: red;
    }
    span {
        color: #fff;
    }
    p {
        color: $yellow;
    }
}
```

есть ли горячая клавиша в phpstorm, чтобы после форматирования код выглядел так?

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;

    .button{
        color: red;
    }

    span {
        color: #fff;
    }

    p {
        color: $yellow;
    }
}
```

т.е. нужно проставить пустые строки между селекторами.
плагин sass-lint выдаёт эти ошибки на отступы между селекторами.
в ручную это будет долго, т.к. таких файлов может быть много.

**P.S.**

уточню, эту настройку нужно именно для `scss`, а в `phpstorm` как раз для `scss` нет такой настройки, как `blank lines between blocks`.
Даже если выбрать `Set from... -> css`, то данная настройка не применяется, т.е. если потом выделить весь код и отформатировать.

Comment: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/06/14/0024/1126/1573990/90/176aec90e9.png
```Ctrl+Alt+L```

Comment: @Ninazu, посмотрите плиз комментарий, добавил в вопрос. т.е. это нужно для scss, настройки для него нет. Эту настройку `blank lines between blocks` я видел, и уже пытался настроить для `css`, а нужно для `scss`

Comment: Можно регуляркой заменить. Благо шторм поддерживает Find&Replace с их использованием
Ищем
```^(\s+)(.*?)\s+\{```
Меняем на
```\n$1$2 {```